# jquery selector not loading

Tags: jquery, tabs, loader

My problem is getting the first tab_content to show on load.
my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".tab_content").hide();
$("ul.tabs").each(function() {
    $(this).find('li:first').addClass("active");
    $(this).next('.tab_container').find('.tab_content:first').show();
});
```

My HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">web</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">graphics/print</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">img</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="gwrapper">
    <div id="gallery">
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div id="description">Welcome to my portfolio. Click any link below.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
        content
    </div>
```

The problem started when I moved the ul class="tabs" above gwrapper (Used to be above tab_container). I know the problem is the selector in this line:

```
$(this).next('.tab_container').find('.tab_content:first').show();
```

I dont know how to jump divs and select. I've looked it up but I can't piece it together. I dont know whether(or how) to use eq() in here.

Example can be found on [jpatrolla.com](http://jpatrolla.com) (then click portfolio)

Comment: Why don't you set them up to be active initially through your CSS itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tabs").each(function() {
        $(this).find('li').eq(0).addClass("active");
        $(this).nextAll('.tab_container').children('.tab_content').eq(0).show();
    });
});
```

The `.tabs` element and the `.tab_container` element in your example HTML are siblings, so you can use `.siblings()` or `.nextAll()` to select them relatively from your `.tabs` element. The difference between `.siblings()` and `.nextAll()` is that the latter only looks for elements that come after the current selection and the former looks at all sibling elements.

Notice the usage of `.eq(0)` instead of `:first`, they do the same thing, select only the first element in the set, but using `.eq()` is faster since it doesn't take mucking around with strings.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YbNJ2/

- Docs for `.nextAll()`: http://api.jquery.com/nextall

**UPDATE**

I normally like to help people optimize their code whenever possible and you can increase the performance of your loop by using either `$.each()` instead of `$().each()` or even better you can use a well formatted `for` loop:

```
$(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var $tabs = $(".tabs");
    for (var i = 0, len = $tabs.length; i < len; i++) {
        $tabs[i].find('li').eq(0).addClass("active");
        $tabs[i].nextAll('.tab_container').children('.tab_content').eq(0).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response jasper, thanks for the effort and the links! this is why I love stackoverflow.

Comment: You're welcome. I added a little bit about making your loop perform faster. Using `for` like I have shown above is a lot faster than `.each()`, so if you have a number of `.tabs` elements then you may want to change-out your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
$(this).siblings('.tab_container').find('.tab_content:first').show();
```

or

```
$(this).nextAll('.tab_container').first().find('.tab_content:first').show();
```

Comment: You my friend are a savior! facepalming myself because .siblings is used in the other part of the script. 
Appreciate your time James! Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0):

When are you using .each() when you only wish to affect one thing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $('.tabs').find('li:first').addClass("active");
    $('.tab_container').find('.tab_content:first').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.next() matches the immediately following sibling which is not the case now after you have moved ul class="tabs" above gwrapper.

If you want to use next, this should work,

```
$(this).next().next('.tab_container').find('.tab_content:first').show();
```